# Eclipse - Ctrl Contrib (Bottom)

Tags: eclipse, button, parentheses, ctrl

For some reason I can't enter parentheses in Eclipse. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> doesn't work. I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> in order to get an opening parentheses (likewise for ")").

I believe the reason for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> "Contrib (Button)" which is some sort of status message at the lower right corner. I'm not sure if it's always been there, but probably not.

[This](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=103956&goto=317500&#msg_317500) is the only similar problem I found in the net, but the solution doesn't work for me, because such a path (Help -> Software Updates -> Manage Configuration) doesn't exist in my version of Eclipse. Help -> Search didn't help either.

How do I get rid of it? If it's not the source of my problem, what is? Going with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>/<kbd>9</kbd> to enter parentheses is really annoying and its not something I'd like to get used to.

Comment: I you are running Eclipse Mars, you might find it under Help > Installation Details. It's probably somewhere in the Help menu, try them all.

Comment: Look in the Preferences in 'General > Keys' and see what is bound to Shift + 8

Comment: @Kenney Thanks, but I couldn't find it. Perhaps there is a way to reset the settings of eclipse?

Comment: @greg-449 Sorry for the late reply, but there is no such combination (Shift + 8) listed. Also, I have to correct myself. (Shift+9) works fine, but (Shift+8) doesn't.

Comment: @greg-449 Actually, there were two such binds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/518080/), which solved my problem.

Went to **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys**, and looked for key combinations that used <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>. There were two such options:
- Import
- Add to Working Set

I removed the hotkeys from them and restarted Eclipse. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for these weired short cuts came up with eclipse sdk. If you downloaded and install the *Eclipse SDK Tests* you will find some weired settings. Like a blue texftfield in bottom right corner with "Ctrl Contributor" in it and also these short cuts.

To uninstall only these packages go to **Window -> Installation Details -> Installed Software (tab)** and searching for **Test**. You should find **Eclipse SDK Tests** and uninstall it. It just adds some non-sense features to your IDE to test if everything works.

Hope it helped and sorry for my english!